# Welch's method equivalence between R (oce) and Python (scipy)

Tags: python, r, audio, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to translate some code from R to Python, but I can't obtain the same result when applying the Welch method to audio samples.

This is the R code with the oce package:

```
pwelch(x, nfft=512, fs=48000, plot=FALSE)
```

This is one of my tries with python (scipy.signal)

```
signal.welch(x, fs=48000.0, window='hamming', nperseg=512, noverlap=256, nfft=512, detrend='linear', return_onesided=True, scaling='density', axis=-1)
```

I have tried several options but I can't obtain the same amplitude coefficient with python. Any ideas will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From a similar problem I know that one has carefully to read the documentations of the functions to learn about the details of implementation. BTW: Do the functions use random numbers or not?

Comment: @jogo. Thanks for the help. I am reading the documentation for some days. There is no random numbers.